# How to stop automatic sliding of bootstrap carousel and make sliding speed slow

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Check this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Va8Un/550/), here images are sliding automatically, I am in need of slide only when user click on right/left arrow. Need help to stop automatic sliding.
I am new to CSS world. Any help will be appreciated.

Edited: I also want to make sliding speed slow.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
margin-top: 10px;
}

img
{
 max-width:100%;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-interval="false">
```

instead of

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
```

Edit: another possible [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358499/preventing-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-from-auto-sliding-on-page-load)

Comment: perfect answer updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Va8Un/577/

Comment: can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030400/horizontal-menu-scrolling